# Replace (mask?) numeric axis labels with custom text

Tags: excel, excel-2010, bar-chart, pivot-table

In Excel 2010, I would like to replace labels on one axis with custom words.  In this case I have several columns and the ID in the database is 7, 17, 27, 34, 41, 48. I created a pivot chart that counts how many times these IDs show up but under each column the labels are these numbers. I would like, for example, `7` to show `Application Gap`.

I have been goggling like a madman but I can't seem to find the terms I need to get the answer I need.

Is it possible to replace these IDs with the words they actually represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (based on Excel 2007!) by changing the row labels in the associated PT.

Comment: Thank you, good sir.  I altered the select query for the pivot table to use a Replace() and now all the columns are labeled properly